# adding pagination to all tables using jtable in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, jsp, jquery-jtable

I have done pagination to a simple table using jtable in jsp.But it only works to that table.I have write a code which will give drop down of all tables present in mysql database.Now how to write pagination code in the way that if i select a table it should display all the data in that table using pagination and CRUD operations from User Interface .I have done it for only one table .Now please give an idea how to make these tables to display the dynamically selected table with pagination.

Comment: I am confused. JTable and JSP are usually not mentioned in the same question, and I'm trying to think to myself, just how would you combine them?

Comment: I'm learning something new every day. I've just never heard of this before. **Edit**: Ah, I see, you're talking about JQuery jTables, **not** ***Swing*** JTables. Big difference. Get rid of the [tag:jtable] tag, since it refers to the Swing beast. Use the [tag:jquery] and [tag:jquery-jtable] tags instead. I've done this edit for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for this requirement (stackoverflow.com/questions/27644483/dynamic-fields-using-jquery-in-jtable)

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to generate the jtable configuration on the selection of your table in the dropdown.
2. Create the jtable configuration for all your table then change (destroy the jtable using $('div1').jtable('destroy') initialize your div with selected table configuration.